# Linq string field range based selection using string type filed

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4

i want do range based filtration on linq query but  property type is string even though it stored numerical data is there way to do this

`VOUCHERNO`  property type is string but now new request came to do range base selection  from to it stores numbers

example  `VOUCHERNO`  TYPE IS string

```
from ........  WHERE(O=>O.VOUCHERNO >=100 && O=>O.VOUCHERNO <=100)
```

This is not full linq query but I cant do this type of filteration
How to handle this

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question to include all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `VOUCHERNO` always contains int values, why not just cast it to int? (or better yet, change it's definition to int)

```
from ........  WHERE(O=>(int)O.VOUCHERNO >=100 && (int)O.VOUCHERNO <=100)
```

Comment: Lovely. care to tell us what error you get, or should we guess it?